# How Do I Update the Swagger UI Documentation in JHipster?

Tags: jhipster, openapi, springfox

In my JHipster app, I have manually updated the OpenAPI spec file (api.yml), following [official instructions](https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/) for API-first development.

However, the documentation (generated via Springfox) does not update, and still lists the endpoints described in the original (default) content of the api.yml.

As per [Springfox's documentation](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#springfox-swagger-ui),

> All content is served from a webjar convention, relative url taking the following form: webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/swagger-ui.html

But there's no word about how to update that. Any ideas/clues welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: So you regenerated your interface from the api.yml but maybe Springfox uses only implementation that you manually created. The webjar part is unrelated, JHipster serves its own version of swagger-ui html and css.

Comment: That's the thing, I haven't manage to regenerate the documentation (the one available at localhost:[port]/swagger-ui/index.html. The spec file has changed, but the generated doc has not, and I want to do that.

Comment: But here what I'm saying is that Springfox introspects the classes for swagger annotations, API-first generates interfaces not classes, if you have manually duplicated annotations that could be the cause, check classes for annotations. swagger-ui.html uses the swagger JSON spec generated by Springfox.

Comment: If your endpoints start with something other than `/api`, then it won't appear in the swagger-ui by default. For example, if your endpoints start with `/config` then use `/(api|config)/.*` here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/f7323c267ef937c19e6c1915bf93b889f9daf0d3/src/main/resources/config/application.yml#L136

Comment: Just to be sure: did you regenerate the application after your change on api.yml?

Comment: Thanks for the details, Gael and Jon! I haven't duplicated annotations, and my newly added endpoints do not start with /api, so I'll look into both issues. And Pierre, no, I haven't regenerated the app. It's my first look at JH, so everything is completely new to me.